# Is there any function in OpenCV to quantize RGB values?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, colors, rgb

I need to quantize the RGB values to 29 uniform color dictionary. I used `rgb2ind(image,29)` in Matlab.

So, is there any function or efficient way to quantize the image color in OpenCV?
(I need to quantize the image color because i want to get a 29-sized histogram of color)

Comment: Short answer : No. Long answer : No - you'll need to roll your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make your own. I can reccomend using HSV instead of RGB (you can convert RGB to HSV with opencv). Once the image is converted, you can then simply use 29 ranges for the H value.

EDIT: I saw this answer might be a bit vague for those who have little experience in computer vision. This [question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2687/why-do-we-use-the-hsv-colour-space-so-often-in-vision-and-image-processing) gives a lot more information about the difference between HSV and RGB and why this is usefull.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have made a uniform quantization using the 3 RGB values. But I'll try the HSV you said. Thanks! :)